# Where can I find the PreExecute method in SSIS script component?

Tags: ssis

I am trying to call a Net.TCP WCF service within my SSIS package. I have set up the script component, changed the .NET Framework to 3.5 in the Service Reference. I am creating the sample package based on the example provided in the below link.

[How to Configure an SSIS Package to Access a Web Service using WCF](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dbrowne/archive/2010/07/08/how-to-configure-an-ssis-package-to-access-a-web-service-using-wcf.aspx)

The link states to override the *`PreExecute`* method but I am unable to find the method within the script component in SQL 2008 R2.

The script component in my package begins with the following code:

```
[System.AddIn.AddIn("ScriptMain", Version = "1.0", Publisher = "", Description = "")]
public partial class ScriptMain : Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase
```

However, the example written in the above-mentioned article has the below code:

```
[Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.SSISScriptComponentEntryPointAttribute]
public class ScriptMain : UserComponent
```

I've tried just copying the code across then to fix the relevant references but no where does it contain a reference for *`UserComponent`*.

Could someone point out what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Cause of the issue:

You are using the *`Script Task`* available on the *Control Flow* tab instead of the **`Script Component`** transformation available within *Data Flow Task*.

#### SSIS 2008 R2 package illustrating the differences:

Create an SSIS package in *Business Intelligence Development Studio (BIDS) 2008 R2* and name it as *`SO_10121670.dtsx`*.

BIDS will be default display the *Control Flow* Tab. From the toolbox, drag and drop *`Script Task`* and *`Data Flow Task`* as shown below.

[image: Control Flow]

Double-click *Script Task* to view the *`Script Task Editor`*. On the *Script Task Editor*, click *Script* page and then click *`Edit Script...`*

[image: Script Task Editor]

*`Integration Services Script Task`* code editor will open. You will notice that the class *`ScriptMain`* inherits from `Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase`

The example it the [MSDN article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dbrowne/archive/2010/07/08/how-to-configure-an-ssis-package-to-access-a-web-service-using-wcf.aspx) does not use this *Script Task*.

[image: Script Task]

On the *Control Flow* tab, double-click *Data Flow Task* to switch to the *Data Flow* tab. Drag and drop a **`Script Component`** from the *Data Flow Transformations* section on the *Toolbox*.

[image: Data Flow Task]

When you drag and drop a *Script Component*, the *`Select Script Component Type`* dialog will appear. You have to choose the appropriate one that suits your requirements. This sample sets the type to *`Source`* so we can view the script editor. Click *`OK`*.

[image: Select Script Component Type]

Double-click the *Script Component* to view the *`Script Transformation Editor`*. On the *Script Transformation Editor*, click *Script* page and then click *`Edit Script...`*

[image: Script Transformation Editor]

*`Integration Services Script Component`* code editor will open. You will notice that the class *`ScriptMain`* inherits from `UserComponent`. This is the component that you need to use to practice the WCF sample code in the [MSDN blog article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dbrowne/archive/2010/07/08/how-to-configure-an-ssis-package-to-access-a-web-service-using-wcf.aspx).

You can see the **`PreExecute`** method inside the *`Script Component`* code that you have been looking for.

[image: Script Component]